# Flag a row in one column based on past value in another column

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

Probably basic, but I'm banging my head against a wall.

Say I have this data table:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(DaystoPeak = c(2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
                 FlagPeak = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0))

df <- data.table(df)

df
 #   DaystoPeak FlagPeak
 #1:          2        0
 #2:         NA        0
 #3:         NA        1
 #4:         NA        0
 #5:         NA        0
 #6:         NA        0
 #7:          3        0
 #8:         NA        0
 #9:         NA        0
 #10:        NA        1
 #11:        NA        0
 #12:        NA        0
```

Basically what I want to do is generate the second column.
I was trying out something like:

```
df <- df[, FlagPeak := 0] 
df <- df[, FlagPeak[.I+2] := ifelse(DaystoPeak == 2, 1, FlagPeak)]
```

But it doesn't work... probably a circular reference problem or something. I've tried a few other things but they don't work either :(

Eg:

```
df <- df[, FlagPeak := ifelse(DaystoPeak == 2, c(0,0,1), FlagPeak)]
```

Anyone able to lend a hand?

Comment: Try the `tail` or `head` function on the RHS.

Comment: @Codoremifa, I'm not exactly sure how to incorporate this.. I haven't really used them before. Where abouts would it go?

Comment: `tail(DaysToPeak, -2)` or something along those lines in your RHS.

Comment: like this? `flag <- rep(0, nrow(df)); flag[which(!is.na(df$DaystoPeak)) + na.omit(df$DaystoPeak)] <- 1`

Comment: @rawr thanks for that, works well! I think I understand it too. I'm new to all this, so exposure to these things is helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @rawr If you put it as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: Or in `data.table` speak - `df[which(!is.na(DaystoPeak)) + na.omit(DaystoPeak), FlagPeak := 1]` - As an aside you don't need to reassign like `df <- ...` when using `:=` - it updates by reference.

Comment: Ah excellent. Good to know. Thanks @thelatemail

Comment: I would do `w = which(!is.na(df$DaystoPeak)); df[w+DaystoPeak[w], FlagPeak := 1L]`. There is an open feature request for syntax like `FlagPeak[.I+2] := `, which I'd also like to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comments have a lot of good options. I'd probably do this though:

```
df[, FlagPeak := 0][DaystoPeak + 1:.N, FlagPeak := 1]
```

This works because `df[NA, FlagPeak := 1]` doesn't do anything.